# Xev not recognizing up arrow key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've been having problems with my keyboard lately.

I'm using Aspire S7 Ultrabook. Though the <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys and <kbd>Del</kbd> key suddenly went crazy.

I press the <kbd>Up</kbd> key, nothing happens.

I press the <kbd>Right</kbd> key, nothing happens.

I press the <kbd>Down</kbd> key, touchpad off sign appears, though touch pad stays on.

I press the <kbd>Del</kbd>Del key, touchpad on sign appears, though touch pad stays off (if it's off).

I have tried remaping the keys but since the keycodes aren't showing up on xev I'm having a bit of trouble.

Anyone had this trouble before? how can i fix it?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Have you been messing with what the keys do at all? i.e. Trying to change what they do by default?

Comment: Not really, only started messing with them after I noticed the problem. Before I noticed what I remember I did was install Android SDK on Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to put a pretty good band-aid on the problem.

For anyone who might have the same problem in the future:

What happened was for some reason the keycodes of my arrow keys and delete keys were changed. Either due to foreign influences or bug influences.

Xev wasn't recognizing my up key because it's keycode was above 255, it is now 425. So I couldn't use xmodmap to remap the up key.

I used instead showkey to view it.

And went through this wiki to change it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes

Hope it helps souls in need ;)

**Edit**

I found another solution to the problem, rebooting the computer and pressing F12 during boot - It will load bootable devices. Just pick the default, it should start working again.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I have read the given link, but can't understand which codes to change. Can you explain me more about which codes to change, scancodes or keycodes or their mapping and change to what values? Thank you :)

Comment: just to echo the other commenter - could you please expand your answer with specific details of what you did? Also you may want to accept it :)